# C++ gsoap memory leaks in my computer

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, gsoap

I use gsoap client in C++ program, but it has memory leaks when calling the defined functions many times. The main codes are:

```
for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){
    struct soap* s = soap_new();
    char* run;
    soap_call_ns__run(s,url,NULL,"123",&run);
    soap_destroy(s);
    soap_end(s);
    soap_done(s);
    soap_free(s);
}
```

when running, the memory will rise up;
I run this on Win7 system; I try it on ubuntu 16.10 and it seems there's no memory leaks.

Can anyone try it and help me ?

Comment: I use umdh.exe to see memory leaks, it shows  54959 allocs backTrace22DA64   ntdll!RtlUlonglongByteSwap+BB9

Comment: I suppose run is being allocated and needs to be freed. I see no documentation for soap_call_ns__run - so you need to read it and see how the result should be freed after usage

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to give soap_call_xxx a pointer to an uninitialized run variable?  When I look in the stubs that gsoap creates for me it checks if the response variable is NULL and if it is returns before assigning.  If it isn't NULL then it uses it as a pointer and calls the soap_default member function.  Your run variable  is uninitialized so ANYTHING can happen.  You need to either set it to NULL for a oneway call or allocate the object so it can be filled in.

Comment: Hmmm.  The current gsoap user guide's example don't initialize the result variable either.  Maybe it depends on the version of gsoap...  What version of gsoap are you using to create your stubs?

Comment: run is freed after destroying soap, I try it on win10 system and there is no memory leaks. Maybe it only appears in win7 system

Comment: Thanks a lot. run is freed after destroying soap, I try it on win10 system and there is no memory leaks. Maybe it only appears in win7 system. this function is generated by soapcpp2.exe with gsoap 2.8.53. I defined it as int ns__run(char* data, char** run) in run.h; an use soapcpp2.exe with -S/-c run.h. try it on win7 if interested.

Comment: Did you tried to call soap_dealloc(run)?